# When trying to copy paste the value of an input field: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box with text.
I want to launch a function when the user presses enter.
The function goes like:

```
si = $("#maincopy_search_input").val();
$("#search_input").val(si).attr('value'.si);
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined(…)

When I do `console.log(si);` it successfully prints when the user wrote in the input... So I'm wondering what the problem is.

Here is my full function which launches upon pressing enter:

```
document.getElementById('maincopy_search_input').onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){
        var si = $("#maincopy_search_input").val();
        $("#search_input").val(si).attr('value'.si);
        launch_ajax();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be cause of typo in attr('value'.si); there is a dot, replace it with comma(, )

Comment: I didn't see that!! That's correct! If you post the answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be cause of typo in

`attr('value'.si);`

there is a **dot** (.) , replace it with **comma**(,)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the dot with comma.
Actually it means setting the value attribute with value stored in the variable 'si'.

It would come like this:

$("#search_input").val(si).attr('value',si);